# Are the criteria for getting the "Breaking Bad" hat in "or" or "and"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

The description of the ["Breaking Bad" hat](https://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/breaking-bad) says:

> vote to close a question, edit it when closed, vote to reopen

Does it mean we have to close AND edit when closed AND vote to reopen the question, or close OR edit when closed OR vote to reopen?

I VTCed one question and the hat hasn't yet appeared (though I know, delays and stuff). Maybe that means AND?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. You vote to close a question.
2. The question becomes closed eventually.
3. You then edit the question while it is in closed status. Suggested edits count if they're accepted.
4. You then vote to reopen the question. You must do this within one hour of editing.
5. You earn hat.

The question does not have to be reopened for you earn the hat.

Comment: Wow it's so subtle! "... edit **it**...", but then the next statement goes with "vote to reopen", which isn't really helping.

Comment: I can confirm the above. See my hat.

Comment: One additional thing: The reopen vote must come (more or less) immediately after the edit. To be precise, the time between 3 and 4 must be under an hour.

Comment: @balpha any score requirement, e.g. if question has negative score, do we still get the hat?

Comment: @balpha Since you're giving all the details: do suggested edits count? (On beta sites, the close/reopen privilege comes before the edit privilege.)

Comment: @Gilles Only if it was accepted.

Comment: @balpha If they're accepted eventually, or does the suggested edit have to be accepted before you vote to reopen? [Prediction: balpha gives up in disgust and http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com only contains the source code of SQL queries.]

Comment: @Gilles I'm pretty sure you have to wait until the edit is approved before casting the reopen vote, but of course being mere mortal I might be wrong. :)

Comment: @Gilles The point is that you make the question better, deserving to be reopened. But you haven't actually edited it and thus improved it until the edit is accepted.